# JSONObject from HashMap - Cast to String failed

Tags: java, json, casting, hashmap

I need to create a `JSONObject` from a `HashMap` of a custom class's `toString` and a float value. I tried the code below hoping that it would just work:

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        return "a nice string"
    }
}


HashMap<MyClass,Float> map = new HashMap<MyClass,Float>();
map.put(...);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(map);
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

What's the best way to create this `JSONObject`? Thanks.

Comment: Which JSON library do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

`HashMap<MyClass,Float> map = new HashMap<MyClass,Float>();`

with

`HashMap<String,Float> map = new HashMap<String,Float>();`

as you said "***HashMap of a custom class's toString and a float value***"

You haven't mentioned how are you putting the values into the hashmap.

But if you using `toString` method of your custom class, then you should put it like :

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
map.put(m.toString,123.45f);
```

Comment: Well, I can't change the HashMap to `<String,Float>` because I'm doing other things with that class. Maybe I can create an intermediate HashMap in which I copy the values of the original one. At that point I should probably create a `JSONObject` though and put values directly into that.

Comment: so you can directly put that object in the map : `map.put(m,123.45f);`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using the [`org.json`](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) library. If you take a look at the code of the `JSONObject` class, apparently they're not using generics.

```
public JSONObject(Map map) {
    this.map = new HashMap();
    if (map != null) {
        Iterator i = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)i.next();
            Object value = e.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                this.map.put(e.getKey(), wrap(value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This map seems to handle entries with a `String` key and an `Object` value by the look of the `keyPool` map they use to manage unique `String` keys. In the comments, its also stated that:

> This is used by JSONObject.put(string, object).

So it would be correct to assume the keys of the JSON objects are `Strings`.

Your `MyClass` type can't be upcasted to `String` directly (`String` is not a superclass of `MyClass`), that's why the constructor is actually complaining about the map, because it needs a map of the form `HashMap<String,Object>` (Note that there's no problem with `Float` and `Object`).

To fix the issue, you have to define a `HashMap<String,Float>` where you should store a `String` representation of your `MyClass` object either by using `toString`.

If you can't use a `String` you can consider using an intermediate structure that maps a code represented with a `String` to a certain `MyClass` object, so you can retain your `MyClass` class.

Comment: How about making MyClass extend from String then? Would that be an awful thing to do? I can't think of any side effect :)

Comment: I'd avoid extending classes like that. It's a "quick & dirty" fix but breaks the general conception of inheritance... it's like saying "Hey, my person is a word!" :). I'd define an ID (a code, a generated String or a number, for example) for a `MyClass` element and use a map to identify the actual `MyClass` element for a certain JSON key.

Answer (score 0):

Both Gamb's and Abu's answers are correct and helped me to get to my final result.

I solved my problem like this:

```
HashMap<MyClass,Float> obj = functionThatReturnsThisStructure();

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

for (Entry<MyClass,Float> entry: obj.entrySet()) {
    jsonObj.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue());
}
```