# Android hashmap converting to JSON in the wrong format

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I've got a random issue that I cannot seem to work out. Given the following code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("method","getProducts");

HashMap<String, String> methodParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
methodParams.put("currency", currency);

params.put("params", methodParams);
restClient.setBodyValueForKey("json", new JSONObject(params).toString());
```

The following hashmaps are converted to JSON and sent to a PHP server.

The server should receive the data in the following format via POST

```
Array
(
   [json] => {"method":"getProducts","params":{"currency":"GBP"}}
)
```

On some android devices (not sure what the determining factor is) this is correct but on others it is being sent as

```
Array
(
   [json] => {"method":"getProducts","params":"{currency=GBP}"}
)
```

As you can see the second hash map is being converted into a string and not being added as a HashMap

Does anyone know what could be causing the inconsistency in parsing the HashMaps?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this post, I think it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963770/jsonobject-from-hashmap-cast-to-string-failed

Comment: Have you tried using HashMap<String, Object> for methodParams?

Comment: Thanks @YoelNunez but that issue is regarding having trouble converting Custom objects to String values. My issue is that the HashMap sometimes isn't being added to the HashMap as a HashMap but is randomly converted to a string first.

Comment: @nEm Would that change how HashMap is added to the parent HashMap or simply change how the type of the value field in the child HashMap is determined?

Comment: I'm thinking if it has something to do with the creation of the JSONObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("method","getProducts");

HashMap<String, String> methodParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
methodParams.put("currency", currency);

params.put("params", new JSONObject(methodParams));
restClient.setBodyValueForKey("json", new JSONObject(params).toString());
```

**UPDATE**

```
// replace
params.put("params", new JSONObject(methodParams).toString());
//with
params.put("params", new JSONObject(methodParams));
```

Comment: Would that not result in "params":"{\"currency\":\"GBP\"}"  ?

Comment: That sounds like it makes good sense. Instead of it trying to work out the HashMap, let it work with an Object it completely understands :) I have implemented the code but will not know the full outcome until tomorrow. I will mark this as right if all is good tomorrow :)

Comment: Sorry it took a while to up vote this - only just got my privilege :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the wrap function which is inside JSONObject class. As it works >= API 19. That's why it not able to convert properly. You can use GSON for that.